# Multiple Transactions Using Paypal .NET SDK

Tags: asp.net, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I have implemented Paypal ASP.NET SDK to carry out payments on my website, where the user pays for the items through their Paypal account.

What I would like to do is seperate products that the user has ordered into different Paypal transactions, so that when the client logs into Paypal they can see them as seperate itemised transactions.

The Paypal SDK suggests that this can be done, since the Transactions object is a collection. This is a snippet of my code where I am attempting to send multiple transactions through:

```
#region Get products

ItemList itemList = new ItemList();

if (_products.Any())
{
    List<Item> payPalItems = _products.Select(p => new Item
    {
        name = p.Name,
        currency = _currency,
        price = p.Price.ToString("N"),
        quantity = p.Quantity.ToString(),
        sku = p.Sku
    }).ToList();

    itemList.items = payPalItems;
}

#endregion

#region Personal Details

// Address for the payment
Address billingAddress = new Address();

if (_personalDetails != null)
{
    billingAddress.line1 = _personalDetails.Address1;
    billingAddress.line2 = _personalDetails.Address2;
    billingAddress.state = _personalDetails.County;
    billingAddress.city = _personalDetails.City;
    billingAddress.postal_code = _personalDetails.PostCode;
    billingAddress.country_code = _personalDetails.CountryCode;
}

#endregion

#region Payment Amount Details

Details paymentDetails = new Details();
paymentDetails.shipping = _delivery.ToString();
paymentDetails.subtotal = _products.Sum(p => p.Total).ToString("N");
paymentDetails.tax = _tax.ToString();

Amount paymentAmount = new Amount();
paymentAmount.currency = _currency;

// Total must be equal to sum of shipping, tax and subtotal.
paymentAmount.total = ((decimal.Parse(paymentDetails.subtotal) * (100 + _tax) / 100) + _delivery).ToString("N");
paymentAmount.details = paymentDetails;

#endregion

#region Transaction --> Sending multiple transactions here...

// A transaction defines the contract of a payment - what is the payment for and who is fulfilling it. 
Transaction trans1 = new Transaction();
trans1.amount = paymentAmount;
trans1.item_list = itemList; // Currently sending the same list of items for testing.
trans1.invoice_number = "Surinder Split Order 1";

Transaction trans2 = new Transaction();
trans2.amount = paymentAmount;
trans2.item_list = itemList; // Currently sending the same list of items for testing.
trans2.invoice_number = "Surinder Split Order 2";

// The Payment creation API requires a list of transactions.
List<Transaction> transactions = new List<Transaction>();
transactions.Add(trans1);
transactions.Add(trans2);

#endregion
```

When carrying this out, I get the following error response from Paypal: "Only single payment transaction currently supported".

It seems Paypal does not allow the seperation of transactions from one request. If this is the case, is there any other way to carry out what I am trying to achieve?